# How to get Sitecore Analytics data into new Sitecore instance

Tags: sitecore, analytics, sitecore8, sitecore8.1, sitecore-analytics

We have a Sitecore 8.0 instance that we want to replace by a fresh new Sitecore 8.1 instance. So I installed a new 8.1 instance, installed the necessary modules and TDS packages and the site is running fine.

However we have lots of Analytics data in the old 8.0 instance that we don't want to loose. Is there a way to get that Analytics data into the new 8.1 instance?

Can I just add the old 8.0 analytics database to the ConnectionString and remove the entry of the new 8.1 one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the Sitecore 8.1 upgrade guide (available on dev.sitecore.net). It has a section on how to upgrade the data by rebuilding the reporting database (this process might take a while). This way you should be able to continue with you old data.

Attach your new site to (a copy of) the reporting database, perform the upgrade steps for that database as described in the upgrade guide (running sql script) and follow the steps for rebuilding the database.

Comment: I didn't upgrade the instance. I installed a new one and installed the content on it. So I have two instances: the old 8.0 with the analytics data and the new 8.1 instance that I want to get the analytics data in.

Comment: yes, but if you want to keep your analytics data you will have to link your new instance to the old data (or a copy) and perform the upgrade on that data as described in the guide.

Comment: I see. Which guide is that exactly? In the Upgrade PDF of the Sitecore 8.1 upgrade guide I didn't find anything related to analytics.

Comment: Check the upgrade guide for 8.1 initial release. Somewhere on page 10 is the part for rebuilding the reporting database. But you should also check previous pages as you will need to run some sql scripts if you attach a copy of the old reporting database to the new version (e.g. on page6 they mention the SXP81_BeforeInstall.sql script).

Comment: Does that mean I can enter the 8.0 analytics database in the 8.1 ConnectionString and then rebuild the reporting DB?

Comment: Yes, if you perform the necessary upgrade steps on that database (at least the sql script mentioned). And use a copy of the database (or make sure you have a backup..).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Here's what I did so far: I upgraded the reporting DB with the script from the upgrade files and connected it to the 8.1 instance. I rebuild the Path Analyzer and Historic Map. Now I see some of the reporting data, but the path analyzer shows nothing. On the next step, where I'm supposed to rebuild the Reporting DB on /sitecore/admin/rebuildreportingdb.aspx, I get the following error message: "Connection string used by aggregation/historyTaskManager/ReportingStorage is missing." I also noticed that the MongoDB connection string doesn't point to the old 8.0 DBs. Do I have to change these, too?

Comment: Yes, you need to keep your Mongo's as well. And setup a 2nd reporting and so on..

Comment: Ok, the rebuilding of the reporting db completed successfully using a secondary reporting db. I now see most of the reporting data, but the Path Analyzer still reports "No data was returned for this request".

Comment: After running "Run new map agent" on pathanalyzer.aspx, that error message is gone. But only the "Internet" dot is shown. No item paths from the original instance.

Comment: If you followed the upgrade guide and are still facing issues, I think it's best to contact Sitecore support. They can have a look at your actual data. It's hard to tell you what is wrong without actually seeing anything..

Comment: Today all imported reporting data is suddenly gone. I don't understand why.